# Why is it true that $\mathcal{H}'\vec{x}=-\vec{\nabla}\phi_b$?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, cosmology

A professor at university made the following claim during a Cosmology lecture:

> In the background we have $\mathcal{H}'\vec{x}=-\vec{\nabla}\phi_b$ with $\nabla^2\phi_b=4\pi G\bar{\rho}$.

I am having a hard time understanding why. He has previously defined the conformal Hubble parameter as $\mathcal{H}=a'/a$, where the prime is the derivative $\partial/\partial\tau$ with respect to conformal time $\tau$, and the peculiar potential $\phi$ as:

$$\Phi=-\dfrac{1}{2}\mathcal{H}'x^2+\phi$$

where $\Phi$ is the gravitational potential that appears in Poisson equation, given by $\nabla^2\Phi=4\pi G\rho$ in physical coordinates $\vec{r}$ or $\nabla^2\Phi=4\Phi Ga^2\rho$ in comoving coordinates $\vec{x}$.

We seem to be working all the time in comoving coordinates. So, what I have attempted to do to get the desired result is to take the definition of the peculiar potential and apply $\nabla^2$:

$$\nabla^2\Phi=-\dfrac{1}{2}\mathcal{H}'\nabla^2x^2+\nabla^2\phi=-\dfrac{1}{2}\mathcal{H}'\cdot 6+\nabla^2\phi=-3\mathcal{H}'+\nabla^2\phi$$

So we have, according to the Poisson equation in comoving coordinates, that:

$$\nabla^2\Phi=4\pi Ga^2\rho\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ -3\mathcal{H}'+\nabla^2\phi=4\pi Ga^2\rho$$

But I can't seem to get what I need. Help, please?